# Google sheets - Look for a cell linked to a date in a different table and output another cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I've been strugling with a problem for quite some time.
[image]

I'm trying to look up the cell C13 in the top table to output the corresponding number in column A of that Table. So for 01/01 monday it would output "1" in cell A15, "2" in B15, "5" in cell C15 and so on.

I've been trying with different kinds of formula's but can't seem to find a fix. Xlookup amongst others didn't work for me as it didn't allow me to give the nth of example. The idea is to have the top table filled with different names with each a schedule.

If anyone has any idea on how to do this, help would be greatly appreciated!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KHpYc_Cpyq_Y7jQyORUPoYiZNba5DuOBCpsJcZmUbBM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `filter()`, like this:

```
=filter( 
  $A5:$A9, 
  $B13 = filter($E5:$Z9, $E4:$Z4 = text(A14, "dddd")) 
)
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197).

Comment: Thank you soooooo much!!!
I've been looking for quite a while but i got stuck on different formulas.